# Estimating probabilities given the probabily of correlated event

Tags: machine-learning, estimation, maximum-likelihood

Suppose we have a sequence of tuples of random variables $(X_i,Y_i)$ where $X_i \sim \text{Bern}(p_i)$ and $Y_i \sim \text{Bern}(q_i)$ are correlated, where $p_i$ is unknown but $q_i$ is known. We get to observe $n$ of these tuples $(x_i,y_i)$. The problem is to optimally estimate $p_i$ as a function of $q_i$. Any references on the problem would be appreciated, as I don't even know which field this belongs to, let alone if the specific problem has a name.

Example: Given the probability that a woman gives birth to four or more children in her lifetime ($Y_i$ is the indicator of this event), we want to estimate the probability that she gives birth at all before age 20 ($X_i$ is indicator), where $q_i$ is allowed to be some arbitrary function of income, education level, geographic location or whatever. The main point is that it is assumed to be *known*.

EDIT: Maybe it needs to be stated explicitly that $p_i \neq p_j, q_i \neq q_j$ for $i \neq j$ is entirely possible. We don't have a sequence of observations from the same distribution, they're all from (potentially) different distributions. Given $n$ observations of $(X_i,Y_i)$, we want to estimate $P(X_{n+1} = 1)$ given perfect knowledge of the DISTRIBUTION of $Y_{n+1}$, but prior to actually observing it.

Comment: you have to specify how X and Y are 'correlated' otherwise one cannot optimally estimate. one example might simply be that X is simply logistic function of Y...

Comment: Are you saying there is no optimal solution to this estimation problem given no prior knowledge on the exact correlation...? That sounds strong.

Comment: Is this your situation?  You know P(Y). You have observations of (X,Y). And you want to know P(X|Y).  If so, P(X|Y) = P(X,Y)//P(Y). Estimate P(X,Y) from the data.for Y = y values of 0 and 1, and calculate the corresponding P(X|Y). Or something along those lines. But I',m not sure I'm understanding your actual situation.

Comment: Yeah sort of but $X$ and $Y$ aren't uniform iid - we know $P(Y_i)$ and want to estimate $P(X_i|Y_i)$ given $P(Y_i)$ based on $n$ observations of $(X_i,Y_i)$ that are possibly all from different distributions. That's the catch.

Comment: You have (X,Y) as ordered pairs. That is (should be) taken into account when estimating P(X,Y) from the data. The marginal distributions of X and Y, whatever they happen to be, even if different, and whatever their dependency, are"automatically" modeled by "nature" and reflected in the paired data.

Comment: To be more explicit: P(X=1\Y=1) estimated as P(X=1,Y=1)/q, where P(X=1,Y=1) is sample fraction of all pairs in which both X=1 and Y=1.   P(X=1\Y=0) estimated as P(X=1,Y=0)/(1-q) where P(X=1,Y=0) is sample fraction of all pairs in which both X=1 and Y=0.  P(X=0|Y=1) = 1-P(X=1|Y=1) and  P(X=0|Y=0) = 1-P(X=1|Y=0) .  Finished.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Yeah actually I kind of assumed the problem was pretty tough but it seems it is very straight forward. Nicely put. The 'real' problem is actually slightly trickier but I'll try to mull it over some more before posting, maybe the solution is just as straight forward. Thanks.

Comment: Err actually I want $P(X)$, not $P(X|Y)$, but maybe that doesn't change much...

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation of your situation:  $X$ and $Y$ each take the values 0 or 1. You know $P(Y)$,i.e., $P(Y=1) = q$. You have observations of $(X,Y)$. And you want to know $P(X|Y)$. If so, make use of $$P(X|Y) = \frac{P(X,Y)}{P(Y)}$$Estimate P(X,Y) from the data.for Y = y values of 0 and 1, and calculate the corresponding $P(X|Y)$.

Note that you have $(X,Y)$ as ordered pairs. That is (should be) taken into account when estimating $P(X,Y)$ from the data. The marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$, whatever they happen to be, even if different, and whatever their dependency, are"automatically" modeled by "nature" and reflected in the paired data.

Explicit Solution:

$P(X=1|Y=1)$ is estimated as $$\frac{P(X=1,Y=1)}{q}$$ where $P(X=1,Y=1)$ is the sample fraction of all pairs in which both $X=1$ and $Y=1$.

$P(X=1|Y=0)$ is estimated as $$\frac{P(X=1,Y=0)}{(1-q)}$$ where $P(X=1,Y=0)$ is the sample fraction of all pairs in which both $X=1$ and $Y=0$.

$P(X=0|Y=1) = 1-P(X=1|Y=1)$ and $P(X=0|Y=0) = 1-P(X=1|Y=0)$ where the estimates on the left-hand sides are obtained using the estimates on the right-hand side.

Addressing a comment: We also have $P(X=1) = P(X=1|Y=1)q + P(X=1|Y=0)(1-q)$, so we can estimate the left-hand side using estimated values on the right-hand side  Note however, that we could have estimated just $P(X=1)$ more directly as the sample fraction of all pairs $(X,Y)$ having $X=1$. And of course $P(X=0) = 1-P(X=1)$.

Comment: I'm actually not sure anymore if I'm not getting something or if there's a miscommunication on my part. To be clear, I want to estimate $P(X_i)$ but I can't actually condition on $Y_i$ - I can only condition on $X_1,\dots,X_{i-1}, Y_1,\dots, Y_{i-1}$ as well as the true distribution of $Y_1,\dots,Y_{i-1}$. Are we on the same page here?

Comment: Like, estimating $P(X,Y)$ as the fraction of observations such that $X=1,Y=1$ is kind of dubious, because I only have one observation of each tuple since they're not iid.

Comment: Are the pairs $(X_i,Y_i)$ iid across different values of $i$, even though $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are not independent for each given value of $i$? When I referred to observations such that $X=1,Y=1$, I meant by that, all the values of $i$ such that $X_i=1,Y_i=1$ and assumed that $i$ is not some tiny number, such as 1 or 4.

Comment: $X_i$ and $Y_j$ are independent for $i \neq j$, yes. But estimating $P(X_i,Y_i)$ as the fraction of $(1,1)$ observations *in total* does not reflect that they're not identically distributed...

Comment: I still don't understand what you're saying.  Consider (X,Y) to be a bivariate random variable.  Do you have n observations of this bivariate  random variable, $(X_i,Y_i)$ for $i$ from $1$ to $n$, and $(X_i,Y_i)$ are independent across different values of $i$? Note that this still allows $X$ and $Y$ to be dependent and to have different marginal distributions.

Comment: Yes, they're independent across different $i$.

Comment: And identically distributed, as a bivariate random variable, across different $i$? If so, that's what i addressed in my answer.  If that's not the case, then you need to spell out very clearly and explicitly your scenario and data, for which you should edit your original question.

Comment: No! $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are dependent. (X_i,Y_i) is independent from (X_j,Y_j). $X_i$ follows a different distribution than $X_j$. $Y_i$ follows a different distribution than $Y_j$.

Comment: In response to your question edit, the distribution of $X_{n+1}$ may have no relation to the distribution of $X_i$ for any of $i$ from 1 to $n$, so why would even the knowledge of $Y_{n+1}$ tell us anything about $X_{n+1}$.?  Unless there's something you're not telling me, and there is some relation between $(X_i,Y_i)$ and $(X_j,Y_j)$ for $i \ne j$, even if they are not identically distributed.

Comment: I mean... clearly the problem is ill-posed in a sense as I didn't even define what "optimal" means in the context. But it sounds like what you're saying is that these $n$ observations can never help you estimate $P(X_{n+1}=1)$ if the tuples are independent, which I strongly disagree with. There's ambiguity in which metric to use, but surely there must exist a reasonable choice such that it produces something that matches ones intuition on what a "good" estimate should be in the context.

Comment: (Intuitive in the sense that "if $p_i \approx f(q_i)$ for the first $n$ observations, then it's reasonable to expect that $p_{n+1} \approx f(q_{n+1})$ for the $(n+1)$:th observation as well)

Comment: No. I was referring to the bivariate observations not being identically distributed across different $i$. If there is some relation between the distributions of these different observations, you need to say something about it. Regarding your "intuitive" comment immediately above, then it sounds like you do want to use the estimate of $P(X|Y)$ per my answer, and if not, I have no idea what you want to do. If you think the more recent $(X_i,Y_i)$ are more predictive than older ones, then weight them more heavily in producing a weighted sample fraction.